# Webapp, return text string not working as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

This is the code in my html page:

```
<table id="table_id" class="display"></table>
<div id="status">Goodbye</div>
```

and then later

```
 <script>
  document.getElementById('table_id').innerHTML =   google.script.run.getTable(); 
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML ='<p>Thanks!</p>';</script>
```

The status part DOES work (I was testing to make sure that scripts were acknowledged in that part of the page.

the getTable function,though, is setting to "undefined".

getTable is in my code.gs page

```
function getTable(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX-t_SjDjQhe3enJYB40');
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName("Form");
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var htmlTable = '<tr><th>Project</th><th>Who</th><th>Status</th><th>Details</th><th>Advance Status</th></tr>';

  for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
    {
    var project = data[i][11]; 
    var who = data[i][1];
    var status = data[i][10];
    var link = data[i][12];
    if (status == ""){ status = 1; ss.getRange(i+1,9).setValue(1);  }      

      htmlTable +="<tr>";          
       htmlTable +="<td>"+project+"</td>";  
      htmlTable +="<td>"+who+"</td>";  
      htmlTable +="<td>"+status+"</td>";  
      htmlTable +="<td><a href='"+link+"'</a></td>"; 





    }//for loop

  htmlTable +='<td><input type ="button" id="arrow" value="-->" onclick =""/></td></tr>';
  //htmlTable += "</table>";

  return htmlTable;
```

}//*****************************************************************************

Things I've tried.

Initially there were "table" wrappers in getTable (but then I thought that might be not cooperating with the innerhtml part). I also tested this function on its own and it does return a chunk of string that is the right html table, so it isn't returning nothing in the normal context.

Do I absolutely need to be using a successhandler and another function here? I feel like this looks like it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the script section to

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML ='<p>Thanks!</p>';
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTable).getTable();

  function buildTable(myTable) {
    document.getElementById('table_id').innerHTML = myTable;
  }
</script>
```

Note that this is not tested but should get you close.  The withSuccessHandler is used to determine what function is run when the server side function is successful.  I would also add .withFailureHandler(tableFailure) and a function called tableFailure for if the server side function fails.

Comment: That did work, thank you! I hate successhandlers and find them so unintuitive.

Comment: @J.G Imagine Your server function running for 5 minutes or more . Unless your server function completes, all your client functions will be put on hold and the browser will hang. Async helps us to avoid such UI blunders.

Comment: @J.G. With this method you also get the failure handler so you can do something when that is the case as well.  And if you have a web app that retrieves multiple sets of data you can end up running multiple google.script.run calls at the same time and deal with each as it finishes, speeding things up quite a bit.